# change two range together - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, range

I have three range .. one range change width second range change height .. i want third range change width and height together with same value(change size).

```js
function x11() {
  var x1 = document.getElementById("m1").value;
  var mm = document.getElementById("mm").style;
  mm.width = x1 + "px";
}

function x22() {
  var x1 = document.getElementById("m2").value;
  var mm = document.getElementById("mm").style;
  mm.height = x1 + "px";
}
```

```html
1<input type="range" min="0" max="200" value="100" style="width:100%;" oninput="x11(this.value)" id="m1">
   
2<input type="range" min="0" max="200" value="40" step="0.5" style="width:100%;" oninput="x22(this.value)" id="m2">
    3
<input type="range" style="width:100%;"  id="m3">

<p id="mm" style="width: 150px; height:40px;  background-color:red;"></p>
```

Comment: What's the problem? Just set both `mm.height` and `mm.width` in the same function.

Comment: Okay... So what's the problem? You essentially copy what you did for the first two but apply a value to the width and height at the same time.

Comment: i know this but i mean if width =40px and height =66px when i change third range i want change value with same value and do not set new value @Barmar

Comment: what is the problem??

Comment: "i want change value with same value and do not set new value" Either you are changing the value or you aren't. Are you saying you want to go from 40px x 66px to something like 45px x 71px?

Comment: i wante change size div with one range and second range @ShakirAhamed

Comment: yes .. i want third range change size div @MikeC

Comment: Why do you pass this.value if you dont use it??

Comment: i used it @Jonasw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the width and height proportionally, you need to save their values somewhere. That way you have a point of reference to work from. Then it's just a matter of adding to those points of reference.

```js
var width = 100;
var height = 40;
var extra = 0;

// Actually use the passed in value
function x11(x1) {
  var mm = document.getElementById("mm").style;
  width = Number(x1);
  mm.width = (width + extra) + "px";
}

function x22(x1) {
  var mm = document.getElementById("mm").style;
  height = Number(x1);
  mm.height = (height + extra) + "px";
}

function x33(x1) {
  // Change the size proportionally
  var mm = document.getElementById("mm").style;
  extra = Number(x1);
  mm.width = (width + extra) + 'px';
  mm.height = (height + extra) + 'px';
}
```

```html
1<input type="range" min="0" max="200" value="100" style="width:100%;" oninput="x11(this.value)" id="m1">
   
2<input type="range" min="0" max="200" value="40" step="0.5" style="width:100%;" oninput="x22(this.value)" id="m2">
    3
<input type="range" style="width:100%;" oninput="x33(this.value)" min="0" max="200" value="0" id="m3">

<p id="mm" style="width: 100px; height:40px;  background-color:red;"></p>
```

The above will work but personally I'd clean it up a bit.

```js
var width = 100;
var height = 40;
var margin = 0;

function setWidth(w) {
  width = Number(w);
  drawBox();
}

function setHeight(h) {
  height = Number(h);
  drawBox();
}

function setMargin(m) {
  margin = Number(m);
  drawBox();
}

// Move box drawing to one function
function drawBox() {
  var box = document.getElementById('box').style;
  box.width = (width + margin) + 'px';
  box.height = (height + margin) + 'px';
}

// Avoid having to set the initial size in CSS
drawBox();
```

```css
/* Separate CSS from HTML */
input {
  width: 100%;
}

p {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- We don't need the IDs since we're getting the value directly -->
<!-- We're also going to use more descriptive function names -->
1 <input type="range" min="0" max="200" value="100" oninput="setWidth(this.value)">
   
2 <input type="range" min="0" max="200" value="40" step="0.5" oninput="setHeight(this.value)">
    
3 <input type="range" min="0" max="200" value="0" oninput="setMargin(this.value)">

<p id="box"></p>
```

Comment: it great but pleas waiting for testing your code to my project

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right you want to scale the element:

```
function scale(value){
mm=document.getElementById("mm");
mm.width=mm.width*value+"px";
mm.height=mm.height*value+"px";
}

<input oninput="scale(this.value)">
```

Comment: what about ranges ? please convert your answer to run code for accepting and vote

Comment: @Jack King : why? You just need to copy the js into your js and add that input and it should work fine...

Comment: see above answer i meant it

Comment: @Jack King : well i think this is not a forum that provides a completely finished solution, it gives examples how it could work, so that the OP has the chance to figure it out on his own and is not simply doing _copy & paste_

Comment: javascript Is not easy for it stackoverflow is available run code  the recipient ike me does not understand parts of the code sir jonas

Comment: @Jack King : you cannot code your whole life with asking questions on SO, so i try to push you into doing it yourself. This is how ive learned it (doing it on my own) :)

Comment: I have a big project and I'm thinking it was established in every part of the project, but some times, my mind does not understand due to fatigue of the spectrum were used to SO